# Behavior of the Array filter function changes after using with Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object array and a map which is needed to filter the array according to the user input.All the user input saves to a map and after it will filter the array and shows the results. My code is same as follows.

```
let items:table = [
{
   userId = "201",
   host = "stable",
   ip = "123.43.23.89"
},
{
   userId = "202",
   host = "stable",
   ip = "123.43.23.99"
}
];

let map = this.getResult();//returns a Map, keys are same as array's object attributes.
//[key="userId ", value="201"],
//[key="host", value="stable"],
//[key="id", value="123.43.23.89"],

let flag = true;

items.filter(element =>{
  for(let key of map.keys()){
       flag = flag && element[key]==map[key];
   }
  return flag;
});
```

This approach dose not work.Can anyone help me with this please..

Comment: Please provide `map` value and expected result.

Comment: Is this ECMAScript or TypeScript? What is the value of *this*? What does *getResult* return?

Comment: @Rob, this is Typescript, Returns a map..@grumbler updated

Comment: @SteaveJones—cool, so javascript tag is a red herring… you could probably just start after `let map...` with a literal for what it returns.

Comment: @RobG...I think their isn't much more different than JavaScript or Typescript Filter function. That why i add Javascript too..

Comment: I suppose you need to move `flag` variable inside your filter callback. Otherwise the value from the previous element will interfere with the current one.

Comment: Define "*dose not work*". What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let results = items.filter(element => map.keys().every(key => element[key] === map[key]);
```

Filter returns a new array and you are not storing the results of the filter anywhere, the original array is untouched.